# jquery colorbox cboxClose is not working in ie?

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I'm using jQuery Colorbox in our web application. when i click Close icon, the colorbox is not closed in all browsers except IE. even, i added additional the following script in my local pages.

```
$("#cboxClose").live("click",function()
{   
   $.fn.colorbox.close();
}
);
```

I also tried with `$.fn.colorbox.close();` and `$.colorbox.close()` and `parent.$.colorbox.close();` and `$.colorbox.remove();`.

Please Provide me solutions for this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('#cboxClose').click()` works for me in IE 10 and 11 still struggling in IE 8

edit:

After a lot of effort I realized that the colorbox plugin I am using (version 1.4.33) needs latest version of jQuery plugin. I downgraded the colorbox plugin to version 1.3.19 and it works fine.